# Store values in 64 bit integer in C

Tags: c, encoding, types, 64-bit

I got a program

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

int i;
int x = 128;
int y = 128;
int z = 2;
int32_t coordinates = x | (y << 12) | (z << 16);

fprintf(stdout, "x = %d\n", (coordinates & 0xFF));
fprintf(stdout, "y = %d\n", ((coordinates >> 8) & 0xFF));
fprintf(stdout, "z = %d\n", ((coordinates >> 16) & 0xFF));
}
```

That stores `x,y,z` in 32 bit register, but its successful ONLY for  `{ (x,y,z)< 256}` . If I want it to be possible for `x,y,z` to get values of `2^10 (1024)` (so  `(x,y,z)<1024`)  how can this happen? I know that I should use a 64 bit register(?)  but I am stuck on this, because something is going on with shifts.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should use a 64 bit variable and...just change both shift and masks. 1024 is 10 bits then shift by 10 and then by 20 and mask with 0x3FF

Comment: There *might be* `int64_t/uint64_t` types in `stdint.h` (but they are not mandatory).

Comment: Your code invokes undefined behaviour on platforms with `int` having e.g. 16 bits. In general, it is a bad idea to shift signed integers, unless you can guarantee these shifts will never invoke undefined behaviour. Which implies to avoid certain values/shift-count combinations.

Comment: Note that three 10 bit fields well fit into a 32 bit integer. Just better use an unsigned. I'm not sure what your actual problem is. If you just followw a pattern, I'd recommend to learn the language you are using and learn about bitshifts and masking. It is very likely you will encounter another problem and then have to ask again.

Comment: Yes it is y<<8 .@AdrianoRepetti thank you for your answer

Comment: 2 answers have all ready answered based on `(y << 12)`.  Changing post to `(y << 8)` is poor SO etiquette.  Rolled- back.  This is a typically early user oops, - nothing to worry about, but best to review post well before submitting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Rather than use *signed* types, use *unsigned* types.  A lot less trouble.  [@Olaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38776877/store-values-in-64-bit-integer-in-c/38777216#comment64925449_38776877)
2. The below code allows `x` to have a 12-bit range before colliding with `y`.   It allows `y` to have a 4-bit (16 - 12) range before colliding with `z`.   It have troubles with a 16-bit `int/unsigned`.

   ```
   int32_t coordinates = x | (y << 12) | (z << 16);
   ```

---

To allow `x,y,z` to have a 10-bit range, shift `y` by 10 and `z` by 10+10.

```
 uint32_t coordinates = x | ((uint32_t)y << 10) | ((uint32_t)z << 20);
```

To exact the values:
(be sure to use the matching print specifier too.)

```
#include <inttypes.h>
...
fprintf(stdout, "x = %" PRIu32 "\n", (coordinates & 0x3FF));
fprintf(stdout, "y = %" PRIu32 "\n", ((coordinates >> 10) & 0x3FF));
fprintf(stdout, "z = %" PRIu32 "\n", ((coordinates >> 20) & 0x3FF));
```

Comment: With unsigned int 32 bit,will be any problem in sending with MPI? Or i should prefer signed ?

Comment: @BillG In this case code could use `int32_t` about as well with `uint32_t` as 2 upper bits are not used.  Use `uint32_t` as part of your [MPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) if able, else change back to `int32_t`.  I suspect `int32_t` is favored - but I'd need to see more of code to best answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 3 fields of 10 bits, those will fit in a 32 bit int.  You can do it as follows:

```
int32_t coordinates = (int32_t)(x & 0x3ff) | 
                      ((int32_t)(y & 0x3ff) << 10) | 
                      ((int32_t(z & 0x3ff) << 20);
```

You first perform a bitwise AND of `0x3ff` with each number to ensure you only get the lowest 10 bits.  The result is then casted to the type of the result to ensure that when the value is shifted it does not shift too far for the intermediate values.  Then each value is places at a 10 bit offset via shifts.

Then you can read them back out as follows:

```
fprintf(stdout, "x = %d\n", (coordinates & 0x3FF));
fprintf(stdout, "y = %d\n", ((coordinates >> 10) & 0x3FF));
fprintf(stdout, "z = %d\n", ((coordinates >> 20) & 0x3FF));
```